# etc/init.d/vncserver: line 33: [: =: unary operator expected

Tags: vnc, vnc-server

While starting and stopping the vncserver . i am facing the following error.But, the service is running fine.SO do any one have the similar kind of error on vnc server startup script.

> "
>                /etc/init.d/vncserver restart
>           Shutting down VNC server: 9:shashikanth.bussa
>           /etc/init.d/vncserver: line 33: [: =: unary operator expected

```
    start() {
    [ "$EUID" != "0" ] && exit 4

    # Source networking configuration.
    . /etc/sysconfig/network
"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of /etc/sysconfig/network file entry.
We need to make sure the option NETWORKING=yes.
Then restart the vnc service.